# Android problem using built in SQLiteDatabase execSQL to update function

Tags: android, sqlite

I have the following code to open a database on the SDCARD and then update a value.  If I run the code as is, it will generally run through without throwing an error but nothing gets updated.

If I single step through each line, it works perfectly.  I have also tried adding SystemClock.Sleep(2000) in between each statement.  Still, it does not run properly unless I single step through this section.

Any ideas?

```
SQLiteDatabase db = openOrCreateDatabase( sdDIR + "/DBNAME.db", SQLiteDatabase.CREATE_IF_NECESSARY, null);
db.execSQL("UPDATE tableName SET value='" + newValue + "' WHERE name='field_name';");
db.close();
```

Comment: @user329174: Use `adb logcat`, DDMS, or the DDMS perspective in Eclipse to examine LogCat and look at the stack trace for your error

Comment: Why is "SQLiteDatabase.CREATE_IF_NECESSARY" in openOrCreateDatabase()? Use "Context.MODE_PRIVATE" instead.

Comment: You may need to use the transactional methods, i.e. beginTransaction/setTransactionSuccessful/endTransaction. On the other hand, like Jacob Ros says below, your example seems like a perfect scenario for using the update() method with ContentValues. Using update() would be less error- and SQL-injection-prone as well.

Answer (score 1):

From the Android SQLiteDatabase documentation:

> public void **execSQL** (String sql, Object[] bindArgs)
>
> Execute a single SQL statement that is NOT a SELECT/INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE.

You need to use [update()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#update%28java.lang.String,%20android.content.ContentValues,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D%29) or [rawQuery()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#rawQuery%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D%29).

Comment: They updated the docs. It now reads:

"Execute a single SQL statement that is NOT a SELECT or any other SQL statement that returns data."